# Swift layout not consistent

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I'm making a simple learning app for myself to learn swift. I try to control my Raspberry Pi with my selfmade swift IOS app. Everything so good so far. The only problem is that my layout is totally different from my preview vs the live simulation... How can this happen?

**Preview:**
[image: preview]
**Simulation:**
[image: simulation]

Comment: How have you laid out your controls? Are you using a stack view? What constraints have you put in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Auto Layout constraints to each of the labels and switches. The fastest way to accomplish this is to open your Main.storyboard file, select your view controller and navigate to:

**Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset To Suggested Constraints**

Make sure you select the option under **All Views in View Controller**.

Answer (score 0):

Preview is just a rough approximation.  You need to run it on the simulator or device for accurate results.